# dao as a member of a servlet - normal?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, singleton, dao

I guess, DAO is thread safe, does not use any class members.

So can it be used without any problem as a private field of a Servlet ? We need only one copy, and

multiple threads can access it simultaneously, so why bother creating a local variable, right?

Comment: If the DAO you are using is thread safe, it can be used as a member variable in servlet without any problems.

Comment: It seems to me that it is thread safe. DAO contains only SessionFactory that is injected once, passed arguments to methods do not change anywhere inside the methods.

Comment: As i said, if you are 100% sure your DAO is thread safe, you can use it in the Servlet as member variable.

Comment: You may find this article and its follow-up JSP/Servlet article useful: [DAO tutorial - the data layer](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html).

Answer (score 1):

"DAO" is just a general term for database abstraction classes. Whether they are threadsafe or not depends on the specific implementation.

This bad example could be called a DAO, but it would get you into trouble if multiple threads call the insert method at the same time.

```
class MyDAO {
     private Connection connection = null;

     public boolean insertSomething(Something o) throws Exception {
          try {
              connection = getConnection()
              //do insert on connection.
          } finally {
              if (connection != null) {
                  connection.close();
              }
          }
     }
}
```

So the answer is: if your DAO handles connections and transactions right, it should work.